# Using LOTAnimationView with Auto Layout in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistoryboard, lottie

Is there a way to use `LOTAnimationView` (Lottie framework) with auto layout? I tried setting the class of a `UIView` to `LOTAnimationView` in my storyboard, but getting `nil` IB outlet..

Answer (score 9):

Should be set like this in latest Lottie version:

[image]

and set animation name here:

[image]

and here is example code:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        animationView.play()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Take an outlet of `LOTAnimatedControl`.

Assign your JSON file to `LOTAnimationView`

```
lot.animationView.setAnimation(named: "checked_done_")
```

Complete example:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lot: LOTAnimatedControl!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lot.animationView.setAnimation(named: "youranimationjsonfile")
        lot.animationView.play()
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Update for the latest Lottie version with [Ashish Kakkad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202193/ashish-kakkad)'s comment.

Change class name `AnimationView` instead of `LOTAnimatedControl`,

and then set property `animationName` from Interface Builder